# Save the Starting Location of a UIView in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

So, I'm trying to save the starting location of a UIView so that the block I've created can/will snap back to that location if it isn't placed in the correct position.  I've created a CGPoint called 'startPoint' and I'd like to set its coordinates to the starting point of the block.  What happens now is that I get the block, and when I release it, it goes to the 0,0 coordinates on the screen (top left).  Not exactly sure what I'm missing.  any help would be appreciated.  Code below for the gestureRecognizer.

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *view = [gestureRecognizer view];
    CGPoint startPoint;


    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        startPoint = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:view.superview];

        view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x+translation.x, view.center.y+translation.y);

        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:view.superview];

    } else if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

//        double snapX = round(view.center.x / 110) * 110;
//        double snapY = round(view.center.y / 110) * 110;

        double snapX = round(startPoint.x);
        double snapY = round(startPoint.y);

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            view.center = CGPointMake(snapX, snapY);
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got the working solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a local variable named `startPoint`.  That means `pan:` recreates the variable with every time it (`pan:`) is called.  You need to make `startPoint` an instance variable or a property so that it gets created once and persists across calls to `pan:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
startPoint = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
```

to this:

```
startPoint = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:view.superview];
```

Also, I'm not sure I can really understand what's going on from your description, but it sounds like you should be declaring `startPoint` outside the scope of this method.